# PopupWindow.setFocusable() not working on Lollipop

Tags: android

I'm trying to hide a PopupWindow, when it is clicked outside, and it works perfectly when the `setFocusable(true)` is set for the PopupWindow. Howewer this solutions seems to be not working on Lollipop devices.

I know there is an other method, when we set a background drawable to the PopupWindow like this:

`popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

This works as expected, but the background hides the elevation of the PopupWindow.

Is there a proper way to accomplish the following behavior on Lollipop: Make the PopupWindow dismissable on outside click, while keeping it's shadow generated by the `setElevation()` call?

This is the complete code:

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(binding.getRoot(), UiUtil.dpToPx(context, POPUP_WIDTH_IN_DP),
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popupWindow.setElevation(UiUtil.dpToPx(context, POPUP_SHADOW));
            PopupWindowCompat.setOverlapAnchor(popupWindow, true);
            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            int[] position = new int[2];
            viewGroup.getLocationInWindow(position);
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(viewGroup, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP, 0, position[1]);
```

Comment: popup windows should already be focusable because its another Window.

Comment: "while keeping it's shadow generated by the setElevation() call?" what do you mean by this

Comment: @RahulKumar There is a shadow around the window when you set the elevation for the popup window. But it disappears if I set a background drawable.

Comment: ok so you need to find that background (shadow) from theme and make a layer-drawable with your background. I am going to try it out myself.